# How to tell when a NSManagedObject was deleted by delete rule

Tags: objective-c, core-data, swift, nsmanagedobject

In an NSManagedObjectModel, some objects are related to others with a 'delete rule' such as 'cascade', which means that when an initial object is deleted, the related objects are also subsequently deleted.

Obviously in a well designed database this would not be a problem, but I recently spent a while trying to figure out why some objects were becoming deleted and realised I had accidentally set a delete rule to cascade, which shouldn't have been.

This made me wonder: is there a way to tell if an object has been deleted by a delete rule, or by somewhere else in the code?

I wondered also whether this would be possible by setting up the equivalent of a destructor for NSManagedObjects, e.g. to run a section of code when the object is about to be deleted.

Answer (score 1):

`-prepareForDeletion` is invoked just before an `NSManagedObject` instance is about to be deleted. That's the place to run pre-delete code.

I don't know of a way to find out, programmatically, why an object is being deleted.

Answer (score 0):

> This made me wonder: is there a way to tell if an object has been deleted by a delete rule, or by somewhere else in the code?

After the fact, no. There's no "delete log" with any transaction history so to speak. So if it was deleted than any trace of it ever existing will be gone, unless you did something manually yourself.

> I wondered also whether this would be possible by setting up the equivalent of a destructor for NSManagedObjects, e.g. to run a section of code when the object is about to be deleted.

Yes. There is the `validateForDelete:` method on `NSManagedObject` that you could implement and effectively "hijack" to do some other things when this is called by Core Data. Whether or not that delete occurred by cascade or directly being deleted... I've not seen of anyway to discern that difference.

Comment: The "parent" entity can know abuot the delete rule and act accordingly via above hook.

Comment: That is true, but that's just the rule, correct? It would tell you that the rule is set to cascade even if the delete was not performed via cascading is my guess.

Comment: Well, you have to start somewhere. If the "parent" is being deleted, triggering deletion of "child", child can now behave differently from the case where it is being deleted independently.